# How to open a new tag right after the current tag in chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, shortcut

I know command + T will open a new tab, which appears behind all existing tabs.
I wondering is there any shortcut to open a new tab right after my current tab?

Comment: This is a general computing problem. Not one related to programming.

Answer (score 0):

Use [TabsPlus](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tabsplus/nikomkkhhpfoeamojhhgpfkpkdlfhfii), it gives you the option to choose default behavior for a new tab.

Selecting "last" will result in the behavior you want.
[image]

However, if you right-click an existing tab, there's a context menu item called **New tab**, which will open the tab right next to it.